# CakePHP 3 Edit Upload

Tags: php, cakephp, file-upload, cakephp-3.0

I was following this [guide](http://www.codexworld.com/handling-file-uploads-cakephp/) to do uploads on CakePHP 3. Using that guide, I select a file, and when I click upload, it moves that file to a designated folder inside the project, sets that folder as the path, and creates a newEntity in the database.

I'm trying to now get this same upload to be able to overwrite an existing entity (i.e. Edit instead of Add).

I duplicated the Upload function in the controller and View and modified them to be used as an Edit. However, upon attempting it, the Edit fails and I do not even get to an error message; the page just refreshes as if nothing has occurred.

The relevant table is Files, which has the following attributes:

- ID (primary key)
- link (the folder where the uploaded files are kept)
- name (the name of the file)
- created
- modified

This is my function in the controller:

```
public function edit($id = null)
    {
        $uploadData = $this->Files->get($id, [
            'contain' => []
        ]);
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $data = $this->request->data;
            if(!empty($data['link']['name'])){
                $fileName = $data['link']['name'];
                $uploadPath = 'uploads/template/';
                $uploadFile = $uploadPath.$fileName;
                if(move_uploaded_file($data['link']['tmp_name'],$uploadFile)){
                    $uploadData = $this->Files->patchEntity($uploadData, $data);
                    $uploadData->name = $fileName;
                    $uploadData->link = $uploadPath;
                    if ($this->Files->save($uploadData)) {
                        $this->Flash->success(__('File has been uploaded and updated successfully.'));
                    }else{
                        $this->Flash->error(__('Unable to upload file, please try again.'));
                    }
                }else{
                    $this->Flash->error(__('Unable to upload file, please try again.'));
                }
            }else{
                $this->Flash->error(__('Please choose a file to upload.'));
            }
        }

        $files = $this->Files->find('all', ['order' => ['Files.created' => 'DESC']]);
        $filesRowNum = $files->count();
        $blanks = $this->Files->find('all', ['order' => ['Files.created' => 'DESC']])->first();
        $this->set(compact('blanks', 'uploadData', 'files', 'filesRowNum'));

    }
```

And this is my form:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create($uploadData, ['type' => 'file']); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('link', ['type' => 'file', 'class' => 'form-control', 'label' => 'Template Link' ]); ?><br>
<?php echo $this->Form->button(__('Upload File'), ['type'=>'submit', 'class' => 'btn btn-primary', 'style' => 'width:25%;']); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->end(); ?>
```

In the controller, I've also attempted to replace if `($this->request->is('post')) {` with `($this->request->is('patch', 'post', 'put')) {`, similar to the Cake baked Edit pages.

If say I was to upload a blank Excel spreadsheet called `Book 2.xlsx` and wanted to overwrite the 4th data entry in the Files table, I would go to the URL `localhost/project/files/edit/4`, select the file and submit.

Upon doing so, no error messages appear, either Cake errors or flash errors, and in the CakePHP Request, I have the following array in POST:

```
link (array)
    name: Book2.xlsx
    type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet
    tmp_name: C:\xampp\tmp\php3B10.tmp
    error: 0
    size: 7823
```

Comment: can you `pr($uploadData)` just above your `save` code .. you will be able to see if there is any error in `errors` key response if any.

Comment: I tried that, but got nothing. I've also tried doing pr($fileName), pr($uploadPath) and pr($uploadFile) to check those were correct, but got nothing as well. What do you mean by `errors` key response? Where do you find that?

Comment: are you able to go inside your if statement `if ($this->request->is('post')) {` ?

Comment: are you also be able to go inside your this if statement `if(!empty($data['link']['name'])){` ?

Comment: I think so for both. With `($this->request->is('post')) {` I do have POST data in Request, and in that POST data, the link array contains the name element, which is not null.

Comment: **Avoid that tutorial!** I don't want to offend anyone, but that tutorial is a rather bad example of all the involved techniques, ie CakePHP usage, PHP upload handling, and user input security in general! It has various security flaws (allows the upload of arbitrary files, to possibly arbitrary locations), avoids CakePHP best practices (for example marshalling input, model based validation, etc), and overall doesn't really explain anything, not to mention all the little mistakes (a string as the default form context, adding dates despites timestamp behavior usage, unsanitized output, etc).

Comment: That being said, your "_**no error messages appear**_" and "_**either Cake errors or flash errors**_" statements kind contradict each other. Did you mean to say "_**neither ... nor**_"? You should definitely test for `'patch', 'post', 'put'`, but that needs to be passed as an array.

Comment: @ndm, Could you provide some better alternative tutorials for CakePHP 3 uploading (the Cookbook has none), either through links or as an answer? I've had a bit of experience with the Responsive File Manager, though I was wondering if there was a way to do uploading in CakePHP 3 natively without plugins, yet still be better than my current one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
if ($this->request->is('post')) {
```

To this:

```
if ($this->request->is('post') || $this->request->is('put')) {
```

**Edit:** As ndm pointed out, arrays work too:

```
 $this->request->is(['post', 'put', 'patch'])
```

Comment: `Request::is()` accepts arrays too. You also may want to include `patch`.

Comment: This works, turns out I had not done it properly (not put it in an array).